# Is there any tool that can save all input data for a unit test?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm working on a project that designed with Inversion of Control in mind which currently has no unit tests. When refactoring a method's logic I would like to be sure that I didn't break anything. My idea is to write the unit test which will pass the data and compare it with expected result. The issue is that there is a lot of input data (usually DataTables and POCO).
I wonder is there any tool that would help me to save the input data for class during normal program run or under debugger for future use in tests?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using the approval test approach such as with [ApprovalTests](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net).

With this approach you can define a gold master in form of a text file and use it as baseline to test against for all further runs of the test.

Comment: Sure, it will take some effort up front to condense all relevant info into a text file. But with that done, this can be a powerful technique.

What are you missing?

Comment: I'm missing the tool that persists and loads data.